# Sous vide pasteurization for pregnant wife

Tags: sous-vide, pasteurization

long time StackOverflow user (and home cook). My wife is now almost 5 months pregnant, and whilst initially I didn't want to serve her sous vide food (she didn't want any) 5 months of non sous vide meals has taken its toll on her!

After looking into sous vide pasteurization it would seem that as long as food is pasteurized, it is super safe (if not safer than any other method).

So am I right in thinking, that as long as food has reached its pasteurized temp for the right time, there are no food safety issues (regarding pregnant women etc).

So technically I could serve her a rare(ish) steak, cooked at 136F, if I slow cooked it over say 8 hours?

Likewise, the first meal I was going to attempt was sous vide ribs, 8 hours at 164F (to be safe).

Thanks!

Comment: Related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/19624/67  ... there are others on sous vide pasteurization, but they all link back to that same webpage & tables.

Answer (score 10):

Pasteurization is the process of heating food to kill pathogenic bacteria, rendering it safe to eat. Pasteurization is a function of temperature *and* time.  Using sous vide, one could easily have a pasteurized rare steak, or even a "raw" egg. So, yes...pasteurized food is able to be consumed more safely by people who are immunocompromised or pregnant.  [These guides](http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html) will be helpful.

Comment: How many millions, or billions of healthy babies have been born without the aid of sous vide?

Comment: Some researchers think that babies develop tastes for foods eaten by the mother while in the womb. I'd say that's an argument in favor!

Comment: So that explains an entire generation of teenagers eating Mc Donalds (coal) does it?  So, according to your thinking, babies born to curry eaters go onto demand curry?

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 and how many pregnant women have been craving for a rare steak or other forbidden food? But desisted for the sake of the child? And we are not even discussing the effects of low iron levels. Speaking of experience (gnawing on "well-done" myself back then): this daddy-to-be is doing something very nice for his wife.

Comment: As for the taste: taste, not demand. Both in the womb and via breastfeeding. And I can attest that at least the milk tastes different depending on what the mother eats. Including "hot" - there was the instance of Thai curry that made my baby refuse to nurse.

Comment: Ah, well, with 6 in total we have a few ideas on this.  None have any strange cravings (well that they tell us about).  All were breast fed, and not once did any complain about the 'origin' of the milk.  But then we are all different.